# URL randomiser in an iframe

Tags: php, javascript, iframe, random

I'm trying to create an iframe which loads a random page from another site. The URL is simply the domain, followed by a number. So far, I have tried PHP:

```
$number = int rand(0,450000);
$page = 'http://www.example.com/'$number;
```

Problem is, I don't know how to create the iframe, so that $page goes into the `<iframe src=""></iframe>`

Perhaps something with javascript? I'm unfamiliar with JS, though. All I know is this from google:

```
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*450001)
```

But again, I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Not sure if you just have a typo for the post or something but you're missing the `.` for string concatenation in your `$page` variable. `$page = 'http://www.example.com/' . $number;`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
  $rand = rand(0,450000);
  $page = 'http://example.com/' . $rand;
?>
<!-- ... -->
<iframe src="<?php echo $page; ?>"></iframe>
<!-- ... -->
```

Or, more concisely:

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/<?= rand(0, 450000); ?>"></iframe>
```

`<?= ... ?>` is synonymous with `<?php echo ... ?>`, btw.

Comment: `<?= ... ?>` only works if the short tags setting is turned on in your php.ini file.  I have worked at places that turn this off.

Comment: Hmm. That appears to work, as far as the page source is concerned, but nothing shows up in the iframe itself, when viewing the page.

Comment: @m.e.conroy: that's why I've explained one is equal to the other. ;-)

Comment: @user1940367: have you specified an actual domain (instead of just `example.com`)? `<iframe src="..."></iframe>` should be all you need, assuming the url it's pointing to is legit)

Comment: Yes, I have. I only used example.com, because the pages I'm testing on are currently local. Do you have a suggestion on a website that uses a similar format of domain.com/number that I could test?

Comment: @user1940367: `$site = 'http://placehold.it/' . rand(50,1024);` ;-) (Will give you a randomly-sized image)

Comment: @Brad Christie - I just wanted the person to understand that its not necessarily available to use, that if it didn't work they might have to change a php setting.

Comment: @BradChristie: That site works, so there is probably something wrong on my end, then. I'm going to go fiddle around with my files and if I don't get it work work later on, I'll probably come back to ask another question. But since you answered my original question, I'll accept it.